# How can I remove leading and trailing zeroes from numbers with sed/awk/perl?

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have file like this:

```
pup@pup:~/perl_test$ cat numbers 
1234567891
2133123131
4324234243
4356257472
3465645768000
3424242423
3543676586
3564578765
6585645646000
0001212122
1212121122
0003232322
```

In the above file I want to remove the leading and trailing zeroes so the output will be like this

```
pup@pup:~/perl_test$ cat numbers 
1234567891
2133123131
4324234243
4356257472
3465645768
3424242423
3543676586
3564578765
6585645646
1212122
1212121122
3232322
```

How to achieve this? I tried `sed` to remove those zeroes. It was easy to remove the trailing zeroes but not the leading zeroes.

Help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` looking for all zeros in the beginning of the line + looking for all zeros in the end:

```
$ sed -e 's/^0+//' -e 's/0+$//' numbers
1234567891
2133123131
4324234243
4356257472
3465645768
3424242423
3543676586
3564578765
6585645646
1212122
1212121122
3232322
```

Comment: You should optimize your regex pattern(s). Why you use `[0]*` instead of `0+`? First, there is no need to use `[...]`, and more importantly you want one or more instances, so use `+` and not `*`. Furthermore, you may combine both patterns into one: `sed -r 's/^0+|0+$//g' numbers`

Comment: You are right, updated. (I prefer two expressions for the sake of clarity)

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -pe 's/ ^0+ | 0+$ //xg' numbers
```

Answer (score 7):

try this Perl:

```
while (<>) {     
  $_ =~ s/(^0+|0+$)//g;

  print $_;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^00*\|00*$//g' file
```

or:

```
 sed -r 's/^0+|0+$//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash example to remove trailing zeros

```
    # ----------------- bash to remove trailing zeros ------------------
    # decimal insignificant zeros may be removed
    # bash basic, without any new commands eg. awk, sed, head, tail
    # check other topics to remove trailing zeros
    # may be modified to remove leading zeros as well

    #unset temp1

    if [ $temp != 0 ]           ;# zero remainders to stay as a float
    then

    for i in {1..6}; do             # modify precision in both for loops

    j=${temp: $((-0-$i)):1}         ;# find trailing zeros

    if [ $j != 0 ]              ;# remove trailing zeros
    then
        temp1=$temp1"$j"
    fi
        done
    else 
        temp1=0
    fi

    temp1=$(echo $temp1 | rev)
    echo $result$temp1

    # ----------------- END CODE -----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by fedorqui, this one-liner will

- strip leading zeroes
- strip trailing zeroes
- **strip a trailing decimal point if one exists and all numerals following the decimal are 0**

  - e.g. `1.00 -> 1` instead of `1.00 -> 1.`

```
sed -e 's/^[0]*//' -e 's/[0]*$//' -e 's/\.$//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk ++NF FS='^0+|0+$' OFS=
```

> 

```
mawk 'gsub("^0*|0*$",_)'   # using [*] instead of [+] here
                           # ensures all rows print
```

---

```
1234567891
2133123131
4324234243
4356257472
3465645768
3424242423
3543676586
3564578765
6585645646
1212122
1212121122
3232322
```